# Slow jboss , application spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jboss

I notice that the application server (JBOSS) takes a long time to forward the POST requests to the JAVA controller.
When I click on a botton in my application (in debug mode), the JBOSS takes 2 minutes before I get to the stopwatch in eclipse.
By analyzing I find that time is consumed by a class called `StandardContextValve.invoke ()`
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Gal Marder](https://developer.jboss.org/people/gal_marder) has some suggestion. You can follow

> The problem has to do with the debug breakpoint. Probably one of them
>   is creating some overhead during the loading process of the EJBs.
>
> Try to remove all breakpoints and then start the server in debug mode,
>   it worked for me.

### Resource Link:

1. [JBoss slow in debug mode](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/62582)

Comment: I have the same problem in normal mode.